# Ordering in Grouped Stacked Graph in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data and code that produces a stacked grouped graph. But I want to order the stacked bar within each group in a decreasing or increasing order of the choice.

How do I get ir ordered within each panel

```
df <- data.frame(
  PPE = c("Gloves", "Gloves", "Masks", "Masks", "Gloves", "Gloves", "Masks", "Masks", "Boots", "Boots","Boots","Boots"),
  Farmtype = c("Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm2", "Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm1"),
  Choice = c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"),
  value = c(10, 15, 8, 12, 9, 6, 14, 11, 20, 5, 10, 6)
)

# Create the grouped stacked graph
ggplot(df, aes(x = PPE, y = value, fill = Choice)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  facet_grid(Farmtype ~ ., switch = "x") +
  labs(x = "PPE", y = "Value", fill = "Choice") +
  ggtitle("Grouped and Stacked Graph") +
  # theme_minimal()
  theme_classic()+ 
  ggplot2::coord_flip()
```

[image]

I wanted the stacked bar to be ordered either increasing or decreasing based on the "yes" choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may work, if I understand your question correctly. The issue you seem to have is that the values for `PPE` require to be in a different order for each facet to display the `Yes` values in descending order. You have to override the way `ggplot` wants to order the variables by giving it a new variable structured in the way you want to display the data. This also means creating a labelling dataset.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)

df1 <- data.frame(
  PPE = c("Gloves", "Gloves", "Masks", "Masks", "Gloves", "Gloves", "Masks", "Masks", "Boots", "Boots","Boots","Boots"),
  Farmtype = c("Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm2", "Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm1", "Farm2", "Farm1"),
  Choice = c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"),
  value = c(10, 15, 8, 12, 9, 6, 14, 11, 20, 5, 10, 6)
)

# dataframe to get value for required order
df2 <- 
  df1 |> 
  arrange(PPE, Farmtype, desc(Choice)) |> 
  mutate(order_val = ifelse(Choice == "Yes", value, NA_real_)) |> 
  fill(order_val)

#data frame for labels

labs <- 
  df2 |> 
  group_by(order_val) |> 
  filter(row_number() == 1)

# Create the grouped stacked graph
# I've simplified your version using `geom_col` rather than `geom_bar`
ggplot(df2, aes(x = fct_reorder(factor(order_val), order_val), 
                y = value, 
                fill = Choice)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(Farmtype ~ ., switch = "x", scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = labs$order_val,
                   labels = labs$PPE)+
  labs(x = "PPE", 
       y = "Value", 
       fill = "Choice") +
  ggtitle("Grouped and Stacked Graph") +
  # theme_minimal()
  theme_classic()+ 
  ggplot2::coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you
I have a follow up question. I tried it with a bigger data and had this issue.


---

Comment: How do you define "bigger data"? And what "issue" did you have? Have you submitted another question on SO?